# Most effective blessed tomes usage

Tags: castle-clash

In Castle Clash a "Blessed Tome" grants one of my heros 100,000 EXP, now I have only just started a new game after being away from the game for atleast a year and these tomes are a slightly different mechanic in the game than I am used to.

Can anyone tell me the level at which my hero should be before I grant him that much EXP?

I ask because:

A) There are "walls" that block the heros EXP gain after 20 levels (sort of like a prestige) and this Tome tops them out at Level 60 even. (this is the level block my heros are at at the moment, after just turning level 40 and have "Prestiged".)

B) I have no idea how much experience is needed to get to each "wall" I want to know when my heros will be high enough level to gain all 100,000 EXP from this tome?

I have been granted 3 of these tomes as a prize for something which I can't remember what and I dont want to waste the excess EXP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [here](http://castle-clash.wikia.com/wiki/Experience), these are the stats to getting any hero to the next level:

```
Level    Equation (x is next level)
2-40     10(x-1)
41-45    400 + 30(x-41)
46-50    550 + 50(x-46)
51-60    800 + 100(x-51)
61-65    2,000 + 300(x-61)
66-80    3,500 + 500(x-66)
81-90    11,500 + 1,000(x-81)
91-100   22,500 + 2,000(x-91)
101-120  45,500 + 5,000(x-101)
121-140  155,500 + 10,000(x-121)
141-145  365,500 + 20,000(x-141) 
146-150  495,500 + 50,000(x-146)
151-160  775,500 + 80,000(x-151)
161-170  1,595,500 + 100,000(x-161)
171-180  2,645,500 + 150,000(x-171)
181-185  4,195,500 + 200,000(x-181)
186-190  5,245,500 + 250000(x-186)
191-195  6,545,500 + 300,000(x-191) 
195-200  8,095,500 + 350,000(x-196)
```

As you can clearly see, your tomes can be easily used to get your hero to level 20 and even 40, as it takes only 7800 EXP to get to level 40, excluding stars, gold, and fires. It gets highly more expensive as you continue, costing 11,100 EXP to get to level 45. Use your lower EXP tomes to take care of the lower levels then start to use your better tomes to create decent leaps to the next level(s) when the hero's level starts to get real high.